# Change innerHTML of class with mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the `.innerHTML` of every element with the class `knopf_leer` . I've tried using Ids `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "replacement"` and it works fine, so I'm quite surprised it doen't work with the class.

```js
function ersetz_mich() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("knopf_leer").innerHTML = "replacement";
}
```

```html
<a class="knopf_leer" onmouseover="ersetz_mich();">hi</a>
<a class="knopf_leer" onmouseover="ersetz_mich();">hi</a>
<a class="knopf_leer" onmouseover="ersetz_mich();">hi</a>
<a class="knopf_leer" onmouseover="ersetz_mich();">hi</a>
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Reading the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is always helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a single element. Therefore, you have to iterate over every element in it and set the `innerHTML`:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("knopf_leer"), function (element) {
    element.innerHTML = "replacement";
});
```

In your particular case, since you're making use of inline `JavaScript`, you can simply pass `this` as an argument and use that instead .

**Snippet:**

```js
function ersetz_mich(element) {
  element.innerHTML = "replacement";
}
```

```html
<a class="knopf_leer" onmouseover="ersetz_mich(this);">hi</a>
<a class="knopf_leer" onmouseover="ersetz_mich(this);">hi</a>
<a class="knopf_leer" onmouseover="ersetz_mich(this);">hi</a>
<a class="knopf_leer" onmouseover="ersetz_mich(this);">hi</a>
```